# Correctly format JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a JSON file which contains objects and an array. Yet I'm missing the `[ ]`-brackets. I don't really know the exact terms for these JSON parts, which makes finding a solution using Google incredibly hard. I'm also a fairly new PHP coder, so I'm still learning. Any help or tips are really appreciated!

**Code to create the JSON file:**

```
$db_export = [
    'account' => [
          'username' => $username,
          'email' => $email
    ]
];


file_put_contents("output.json", json_encode($db_export, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Which outputs as:

```
{
  "account": {
     "username": "test",
     "email": "test@domain.com"
  }
}
```

What it's supposed to be:

```
{
  "account": [
    {
      "username": "test",
      "email": "test@domain.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `[]` characters will help. This creates an array inside the array.

```
$db_export = [
    'account' => [[ // <--- Added
      'username' => $username,
      'email' => $email
    ]] // <--- Added
];


file_put_contents("output.json", json_encode($db_export, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

This is how you get the result you want.

Output :

```
{ "account": [ { "username": null, "email": null } ] }
```

I guess it was a little simple :)

Comment: You should provide an explanation with your answer.

Comment: Whatever you think will help the questioner understand your answer, and why it addresses their questions.  Try and keep in mind that people may find your answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this to explain what is going on with the original answer.  You can find this same information in the [json_encode php manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), in the example sections.

With any simple PHP array, json_encode will transform the PHP array into a JSON array:

```
$simple = array('apple', 'banana', 'coconut');
echo json_encode($simple);
```

Returns:

> ["apple","banana","coconut"]

Any associative array will be turned into a json object ***{}*** and each associative key will become a property name.

```
$associative = array('breakfast' => 'apple', 'lunch' => 'banana', 'dinner' => 'coconut');
echo json_encode($associative);
```

Returns:

> {"breakfast":"apple","lunch":"banana","dinner":"coconut"}

In your example, you have an array with an associative key 'account' that contains an array with 2 child elements, each with an associative key.
  This is the reason json_encode() is turning your structure into json objects.

In @Smokie's answer, the addition of an extra parent array that is "simple" ie. not keyed with a name, causes json_encode (following it's simple transformation rules) to create a javascript array, which it then sticks the javascript object inside of.

```
$username = 'test user';
$email = 'foo@bar.com';


$db_export = [
    'account' => [[ // <--- Added
      'username' => $username,
      'email' => $email
    ]] // <--- Added
];
var_dump($db_export);
```

Returns:

```
array(1) {
  ["account"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["username"]=>
      string(9) "test user"
      ["email"]=>
      string(11) "foo@bar.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Here I use var_dump as a quick debugging tool to show what the PHP array looks like.  The important thing to note is that 'account' is now an array(1) with one element ( the 0th element) that contains your original child array.

Presumably you need this because the assumption is that an account could have multiple accountname/email address pairs.  If that isn't the case, I would question why you need to force a useless array.  I personally don't see how an 'account' could have multiple username/email pairs associated with it.

With that said, this code should further illustrate how this all works, and why:

```
$username = 'test user';
$email = 'foo@bar.com';

$db_export = [
    'account' => [[ // <--- Added
      'username' => $username,
      'email' => $email
    ]] // <--- Added
];

//Add another username/email pair to account
$db_export['account'][] = ['username' => 'test2 user', 'email' => 'test2@bar.com'];

echo json_encode($db_export, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Returns:

```
{
    "account": [
        {
            "username": "test user",
            "email": "foo@bar.com"
        },
        {
            "username": "test2 user",
            "email": "test2@bar.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No worries, and congrats on your accepted answer and upvotes ;)

Comment: Perfect! This clears up a lot for me. I really appreciate it.